# Integral and Sum

Tags: calculus

Let be a real interval line $[a,b]$ and define the continuos function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. If split this interval in $\left\{{t
_k, k=1,...,L+1}\right\}$ where $t_1=a$ and $t_{L+1}=b$. I will be able to say

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^{L+1}\int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}}f(x)dx?$$

Answer (score 3):

Almost.  You want the last interval to be $[t_L,t_{L+1}]$, not $[t_{L+1},t_{L+2}]$.

Comment: then the sum goes up to 5?

Comment: 5?  Where do you get 5?